# Remove text with jquery button

Tags: jquery, button, removeall

Just wondering why my remove button is not working?
I really don´t see my mistake, hope someone can help me quick... thanks

html:

```
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'>
     <input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'>
</div>
<p class="sm"><strong><a href="#" id='break1' data-type="text" data-pk="1" data-title="" >3 </a></strong><a href="#" id="break2" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-title="">&nbsp;NORMAL</a><span>TEXT</span>
</p>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
$("‪#removeButton‬").click(function () {
  if(counter==1){
    alert("No more textbox to remove");
   return false;
}

counter--;

$("‪#TextBoxDiv‬" + counter).remove();

});

});
```

or
please also see:
[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/r5yyLb9b/6/)

Comment: your fiddle is different from your code..check it pls

Comment: Please Compare fiddle and your answer.

Comment: Sorry, but if I add more code I have to write more... this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r5yyLb9b/6/) is the right one...

Comment: I think it might be caused by this line: $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline'; I am seeing an error in the console. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'defaults' of undefined

Comment: thanks but that´s just for the x-editable, so it does not interfere with the remove button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem at last. Your `removeButton` click event has some unicode characters which are the problem. I have  rewrite the click events in `document.ready` and its working fine.

```
$("#removeButton").click(function () {
     if (counter == 1) {
        alert('No more taxtbox to remove');
        return false;
     }

     counter--;

     $('#TextBoxDiv' + counter).remove();
});
```

Update Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r5yyLb9b/8/